# Method for cascading soft deletes in parent-child relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, soft-delete

I have a simple schema in which soft deletes are used (that's how it is designed and that can't be changed). There are two tables that participate in the schema: `Company (id, is_deleted)` and `Employee (id, company_id, is_deleted)` where `company_id` ofcourse is a FK to the `Company` table. The rules are:

- If a `Company` has `is_deleted = true`, then all `Employee` referring to that company should have `is_deleted = true`.
- But an `Employee` may have `is_deleted = true` even if the parent `Company` has `is_deleted = false`.

My two problems are a) how to enforce these constraints? b) how to easiest ensure that `is_deleted = true` is cascaded when a `Company` is soft-deleted.

I added the tags postgresql and sql server because those are the databases I'm mostly interested in. If there are other solutions in other rdbms:es I'd like to hear about them too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the only way to cascade values like that is by using ON UPDATE CASCADE. To do *that*, the column "is_deleted" has to be part of a unique constraint.

That alone isn't too hard. If company.id is your primary key, then the pair of columns {id, is_deleted} will also be unique. A unique constraint on that pair of columns would allow you to cascade updates through a foreign key reference.

But that won't work in *your* case, because you need to allow referencing values to be *different* from the referenced values.

So in your case, I think you have three options.

- Triggers
- Stored procedures
- Application code

In all those cases, you need to pay attention to permissions (probably revoking delete permissions) and to cases that can avoid your code. For example, the dbms command-line interface and GUI interface can be used to get around constraints in application code and, depending on permissions, in stored procedures.

Comment: Triggers are the only sensible way forward. Application code can't guarantee to be called and stored procedures (functions in PG) don't buy you anything over a simple trigger here.

Comment: Not sure how triggers will help me ensure the data integrity? If Employee.is_deleted = false then Company.is_deleted = false should also hold true. Can triggers guarantee that?

Comment: Triggers don't offer guarantees *in the same way* that declarative constraints do, but yes, you can write triggers in such a way that changing companies.is_deleted to true will execute a SQL statement that sets employees.is_deleted to true for that company.