# How do I Cascade a SoftDelete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, soft-delete

After checking these SO articles: [cascade-delete-in-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293576/cascade-delete-in-entity-framework), [ef6-1-soft-delete-with-cascade-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728029/ef6-1-soft-delete-with-cascade-delete), [cascading-soft-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506432/cascading-soft-delete), [method-for-cascading-soft-deletes-in-parent-child-relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307978/method-for-cascading-soft-deletes-in-parent-child-relationships) and [reasons-for-cascading-soft-deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522911/reasons-for-cascading-soft-deletes) and not finding a solution...

I have SoftDelete working for my Entity Models. I have overridden `SaveChanges()` in my Context:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach (DbEntityEntry<ISoftDeletable> entity in ChangeTracker.Entries<ISoftDeletable>())
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entity.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I have set CascadeOnDelete for my Child Entities. Because I override the deleted `EntityState` it doesn't cascade. Does anybody know a way to put only the Navigation properties in a `foreach` loop? Or a better way to handle SoftDeletes?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I saw [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13308176/261050) on the right of this SO page.

Comment: @Maarten I saw that, but a Trigger cannot check if an record has inherited ISoftDeletable.

Comment: You can add triggers to the database in the migration-code, based on the presence of ISoftDeletable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this SO Article [entity-framework-6-code-first-cascade-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314113/entity-framework-6-code-first-cascade-delete)...

I realized, I was grabbing and and deleting my entity like this:

```
var entity = context.Parent.FirstOrDefault();
context.Parent.Remove(entity);
```

When I needed to grab the entire Graph like this:

```
var entity = context.Parent.Include("Children").FirstOrDefault();
context.Parent.Remove(entity);
```

Thank you for your input @Maarten